# How do I get bids or listed NFTs using the cardano serialization libray?

Tags: wallet, nft, transaction

We're building a marketplace for cardano and we're aware that the owned tokens/nfts can be fetched via the getBalance() function. How do we get the bids or lists (for sale) for a particular owner address? Is this stored and decoded somewhere in the blockchain much like the owned nfts? THanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the bids and the listings of NFTs directly from the wallet that is bidding or selling. You need to know which Marketplace (smart contract) has that wallet used and get the information from there.

For example, you can check the contracts of the most popular Marketplace in Cardano (jpg.store) here: https://github.com/jpg-store/contract-v2

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't get bids information from blockchain itself.
Since those information are on marketplace smart contract (Jpg.store).

But you can get these information using some provided API.

For example, you can use api which is provided by CNFT.TOOLS.

https://cnft.tools/

Here is example of api.

[https://api.cnft.tools/api/external/${policyId}/](https://api.cnft.tools/api/external/$%7BpolicyId%7D/)

This api will give you the current price, and whether nfts are on sale or not, and their metadata, etc...

Hope this will help you.